# Calculating FIR filter coefficients with the windowing method and Convolution algorithm

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, convolution, bandpass, digital-filters

Please advice how to calculate FIR filter coefficients with the windowing method using the Rectangular Window function and convolution method? What utility or FIR design application can perform this task?

[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me.  The equation you include is just the standard convolution of the signal $x$ with an $M$-tap FIR filter $h$. I don't understand what a "Rectangular Window FIR type filter" is? Is it just a rectangular window? In that case, $h[j] = 1$ for $j=0,1,\ldots,M-1$ and zero for all other values of $j$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, that's standard equation for convolution.I mean design FIR filter with the windowing method using the Rectangular Window function and the above algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

draw your desired frequency response.  uniformly sample that frequency response $\frac{N}{2}$ times from DC up to just below Nyquist.  reflect those $\frac{N}{2}-1$ samples (not the DC values) as complex conjugate in the upper half of the frequency response above Nyquist.  do the inverse FFT.  if it's rectangular window, you're done.

Comment: well, what program is suitable to calculate this?

Comment: the calculation of $h[n]$ is done with the FFT.  the specification of $H[k]$ is done by the user.